# How to resize a figure in Beamer?

Tags: beamer, scaling

In my presentation I put `\tikzpicture`, `cases` or `\array` in `\figure`, I am wondering if it is possible to resize the whole picture including `caption` with a factor. It seems that `\resizebox{<horizontal size>}{<vertical size>}{...}` does not work here...

Could anyone help? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend to avoid using figure environments in beamer, because usually the figures are not intended to float in presentations, and they don't do it as Herbert commented. It can avoid confusion with floats in standard LaTeX. If you just use `figure` because you need captions, you could do it with the `\captionof` command of the `caption` package instead.

Here's an example, where a `minipage` of a small size `.3\textwidth` is used together with a caption, and enlarged by `\resizebox` to `\textwidth`, the whole box including the caption is scaled.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
\centering
 $\begin{array}{c}
    \sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} x_i
  \end{array}$
\captionof{figure}{Test figure}
\end{minipage}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: resized figure with caption in beamer frame]

It would cause an error if `figure` with `\caption` would be used here instead of `minipage`. Note, by using the `caption` package you can benefit from further features of this great package.

Comment: inside `beamer` the `figure` is not a floating object

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\newsavebox\IBox
\newenvironment{resizefig}[1][\textwidth]
 {\gdef\figWidth{#1}%
  \begin{lrbox}{\IBox}
  \varwidth{\textwidth}
  \figure\centering}
 {\endfigure\endvarwidth\end{lrbox}%
   \resizebox{\figWidth}{!}{\usebox\IBox}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{foo}{bar}
\begin{resizefig}[0.8\textwidth]
 $\begin{array}{c}
    \sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} x_i
  \end{array}$
\caption{Test figure}
\end{resizefig}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]