# \bgroup and \egroup?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, formatting, environments, grouping

So I've been looking to expand on the following bit of code (a hack to not screw up the margins when using oversized figures):

```
\noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{%
\begin{tabularx}{1.5\textwidth}{XX}
  \blindtext & \blindtext
\end{tabularx}
}
```

I wanted to turn this into an environment, so was thinking of doing the following:

```
\newenvironment{figurehack}{\noindent\makebox[\textwidth]\bgroup}{\egroup}
```

This throws a strop, LaTeX decides to insert the "missing" brace. So to see if this was a newenvironment quirk, I tried the following bit of code:

```
\noindent\makebox[\textwidth]\bgroup%
\begin{tabularx}{1.5\textwidth}{XX}
  \blindtext & \blindtext
\end{tabularx}
\egroup
```

LaTeX once again tries to insert the "missing" brace. Any suggestions how I can resolve this?

Comment: You must save the contents in a `savebox`. An example can be found on tex stackexchange: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26881/how-to-resize-a-figure-in-beamer

Comment: For me it's duplicated.

Comment: @Macro: `\makebox` doesn't scale, so a fail the duplication. It is true that you need to store the content in a box, but this doesn't make it a duplicate just because this was also required for the other question.

Comment: @Martin: The linked question was an example how to use savebox ;-)

Comment: @Macro: Ah, ok. Please link to the duplicated question then. In your first comment you should have linked to the *answer* which uses savebox, not to the question BTW.

Answer (score 14):

You can only use `\bgroup` and `\egroup` as a replacement for `{` and `}` if LaTeX is expanding the content like it does for low-level boxing commands, but not when it is looking for an macro argument. The `\makebox` macro reads the content as argument not as box, so your attempt doesn't work. I wrote the `realboxes` package which provides variants of all `\...box` macros which read the content as real boxes using my other package `collectbox`. Simply load `realboxes` and use `\Makebox` instead:

```
\newenvironment{figurehack}{\noindent\Makebox[\textwidth]\bgroup}{\egroup}
```

Also have a look on my `adjustbox` package which provides an `\adjustbox` macro and `adjustbox` environment. It also allows `\bgroup`/`\egroup` and provides many options which can be easily combined. A `\makebox[\textwidth]` (which by default centers the content) can be done using `\adjustbox{center=\textwidth}`. The `\textwidth` is already the default value, so `\adjustbox{center}` would be enough.

Answer (score 5):

You can easily collect information that is meant to span from `\<myenv>` to `\<endmyenv>` by using the [`environ` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/environ). The contents of the environment is subsequently contained in the `\BODY` macro, giving you access to provide it as argument to another macro or environment. Not sure whether this addresses your needs, but here's a mock-up:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}%
\usepackage{tabularx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx
\usepackage{blindtext}% http://ctan.org/pkg/blindtext
\usepackage{environ}% http://ctan.org/pkg/environ
\NewEnviron​{mybox}[1][\textwidth]{% \begin{mybox}[..] ... \end{mybox}
  \noindent\makebox[#1]{%
    \BODY% Typeset contents
  }
}%
\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}
  \begin{tabularx}{1.5\textwidth}{XX}
    \blindtext & \blindtext
  \end{tabularx}
\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

In the above example, the default if no optional argument is specified, is `\textwidth`.

[image]