# Error: Missing } inserted. \end{center} (followed by: )

Tags: tables, errors

I'm getting this error message in a document, which contains three tables.

> Error: Missing } inserted. \end{center} (followed by: )

I have no idea why, I reviewed it like ten times, but might overvlook something. Have a look at my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin={2cm,2cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}

\title{Addendum \\ Beispieldatenbanken}
\author{}
\date{}

\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\maketitle

\section{Kunden}
    \begin{center}
        \tiny
        \bgroup
        \def\arraystretch{1.5}
        \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|}
            \hline
            \rowcolor{Gray}
            KNr & Name & Stadt & Saldo & Rabatt \\ 
            \hline
            1 & Legrand & Genf & -1080,00 & 0.10 \\
            \hline
            2 & Mart & Basel & -800,00 & 0.20 \\
            \hline
            3 & Frei & Basel & 0,00 & 0.10 \\
            \hline
            4 & Janvier & Genf & 0,00 & 0.10 \\
            \hline
            5 & Rosi & Lugano & 0,00 & 0.05 \\
            \hline
            6 & Meier & Z"urich & -3800,00 & 0.05 \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}

\section{Produkte}

    \begin{center}
        \tiny
        \bgroup
        \def\arraystretch{1.5}
        \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
            \hline
            \rowcolor{Gray}
            Pnr & Bez & Gewicht & Preis & Lagerort & Vorrat \\ 
            \hline
            1 & Papier & 2000 & 20.00 & Basel & 10000 \\
            \hline
            2 & Platte & 1000 & 2500.00 & Z"urich & 400 \\
            \hline
            3 & Drucker & 5000 & 2000.00 & Genf & 200 \\
            \hline
            4 & Bildschirm & 5000 & 3000.00 & Genf & 80 \\
            \hline
            5 & CDs & 0.500 & 20.00 & Basel & 5000 \\
            \hline
            6 & Maus & 0.250 & 100.00 & Basel & 200 \\
            \hline
            7 & Speicher & 0.100 & 200.00 & Bern & 2000 \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}

        (...) % two other tables of the same form

    \end{document}
```

This error message appears at every `\end{center}` line. How can I fix this?

Comment: If you have such problems it is often usefull to comment out the code line by line. This way it is quite easy to find out that the \bgroup is the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the spurious `\bgroup` at the beginning of the table. It translates into `{` which has then no counterpart.

As well, I have to say a note about `\tiny`: modifying font size to fit a table in a given space is a very bad idea. I recommend you to look at the [`rotating` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/rotating).

Comment: That worked, thank you. May I ask what \bgroup actually is? I saw this in an example in relation to change the color of a row in a table. Further I don't use to fit the table, I actually want to shrink the fontsize in the table.

Comment: `\bgroup` changes itself into `{` at the place when the code is executed, not when it is read. Therefore definitions like `\newenvironment{myenv}{\vbox\bgroup}{\egroup}` are valid. If you tried `\newenvironment{myenv}{\vbox{}{}}` it would (obviously) not work as expected (`\newenvironment` would see 2 arguments `myenv` and `\vbox{}{}`, not 3 as desired).

Comment: @ValentinoRu `\bgroup` is in many cases like a `{` (not in all cases, though; see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27972/bgroup-and-egroup, for instance.