# How to make mhchem work with \bgroup and \egroup satements?

Tags: tables, grouping, mhchem

I am trying to create a table in which a column consists entirely of chemical formulae. I would like to use the array package to automatically insert the `\ce{...}` command, taking the cell's content as argument.

I understand from “[\bgroup and \egroup?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27972/33413) ” that `\bgroup` and `\egroup` only work for replacements for low level commands like `\textbf`. Unfortunately I do not understand how to use the `realboxes` package provided there to make it work. I cannot assess if it is appropriate for that task in the first place.

Here is a minimal *not* working example of what I am trying to do:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{>{\textbf\bgroup}l<{\egroup}%
                  >{\ce\bgroup}l<{\egroup}}\hline
    R1 & -C6H5 \\
    R2 & -C6H4F \\\hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The answer you cite doesn't say that `\bgroup` and `\egroup` work with `\textbf`. They just seem to, but it's by pure chance.

Comment: @egreg Thank you for the clarification. I thought `\textbf` is a low level command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The package `collcell` is your friend for this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,collcell}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries}l
                  >{\collectcell\ce}l<{\endcollectcell}}\toprule
    R1 & -C6H5 \\
    R2 & -C6H4F \\\bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that I also used `booktabs` for the table rules. Last but not least, you don't need `\textbf`, you can use `\bfseries` which does not take an argument.